# Variable is already declared in the upper scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I have a code that is responsible for sending messages, but it's with an error.

```
    <div id="block-messages">
      <ul class="block-messages">
        <li v-for="(message, index) in messages" :key="index" class="mess">
          <b>{{ message.time }}</b>
          <b :style="{ color: message.colornick }" style="margin-left: 8px;">{{ message.nick }}</b>:
          <span :style="{ color: message.colortext }">{{ message.msg }}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Errors:

```
warning  Variable 'message' is already declared in the upper scope
```

What should i do?

Comment: Is there `message` value in data or in props?

Comment: yes, ```message``` in data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment there's `message` value in data.

That is why the error happens.

You can avoid this by renaming one of `message` variables in the template or in data like below (I renamed the value in `v-for`):

```
<div id="block-messages">
  <ul class="block-messages">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in messages" :key="index" class="mess">
      <b>{{ item.time }}</b>
      <b :style="{ color: item.colornick }" style="margin-left: 8px;">{{ item.nick }}</b>:
      <span :style="{ color: item.colortext }">{{ item.msg }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```